# Plotly: How to add dropdown menu for every subplot?

Tags: button, drop-down-menu, plotly, trace, subplot

I need to create two subplots with a dropdown menu and title for each graph. (side-by-side comparison). In addition, I 'd like to have a shared y-axis.

As for now, I have only one dropdown menu that change both graphs.

The code is following: (note that a df consists of 2 columns and datetimeindex).

```
    import plotly.offline as py
    import plotly.graph_objs as go
    from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot, plot
    from plotly import tools
    
    labels = ["Vol", "R"]
    
    
    fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
    
    trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                             y=df['Stock1'].rolling(window=12).std(),
                             mode='lines'
                            )
    trace2 = go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                             y=df['Stock1'],
                             mode='lines'
                            )
    
    fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 1)
    
    trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                             y=df['Stock2'].rolling(window=12).std(),
                             mode='lines'
                            )
    trace2 = go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                             y=df['Stock2'],
                             mode='lines'
                            )   
    fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 2)
    fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 2)
    
    
    # Create buttons for drop down menu
    buttons = []
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        visibility = [i==j for j in range(len(labels))]
        button = dict(
                     label =  label,
                     method = 'update',
                     args = [{'visible': visibility},
                         {'title': label}])
        buttons.append(button)
    
    updatemenus = list([
        dict(active=-1,
             x=-0.15,
             buttons=buttons
        )
    ])
    
    fig['layout']['title'] = 'Title'
    fig['layout']['showlegend'] = False
    fig['layout']['updatemenus'] = updatemenus
    
    iplot(fig, filename='dropdown')
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [empet's helpful answer](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-create-a-button-for-the-certain-subplot/34655) in the Plotly forum, the important thing to know is that the `visible` key has length equal to the total number of traces in `fig.data`.

In your case, you have four traces that correspond to Stock 1 (Vol), Stock 1 (R), Stock 2 (Vol) and Stock 2 (R) which is the order in which you added these traces. So we can create 4 buttons to toggle the visibility feature of each trace and pass them as a list to the `updatemenus` dictionary.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot, plot
from plotly import tools

## recreate some random data
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(365,2)), columns=['Stock1','Stock2'], index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', end='12/31/2019'))

labels = ["Vol", "R"]


fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                         y=df['Stock1'].rolling(window=12).std(),
                         mode='lines'
                        )
trace2 = go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                         y=df['Stock1'],
                         mode='lines'
                        )

fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 1)

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                         y=df['Stock2'].rolling(window=12).std(),
                         mode='lines'
                        )
trace2 = go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                         y=df['Stock2'],
                         mode='lines'
                        )   
fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 2)


## visible key for traces are in the order you append them

button1 = dict(method='update', 
               args=[{"visible": [True, False, False, False] }], 
               label="Stock 1, Vol" )
button2 = dict(method='update', 
               args=[{"visible": [False, True, False, False] }], 
               label="Stock 1, R" )   
button3 = dict(method='update', 
               args=[{"visible": [False, False, True, False] }], 
               label="Stock 2, Vol" )
button4 = dict(method='update', 
               args=[{"visible": [False, False, False, True] }], 
               label="Stock 2, R" )   

updatemenus = list([
    dict(active=-1,
         x=-0.15,
         buttons=[button1, button2, button3, button4]
    )
])

fig['layout']['title'] = 'Title'
fig['layout']['showlegend'] = False
fig['layout']['updatemenus'] = updatemenus

iplot(fig, filename='dropdown')
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to control each of the subplots individually. In other words, I would like to choose what to plot independently. For ex, on the 1st subplot  I would like to plot stock1, but on the 2d - volatility for stock1. ( Imagine, if you have at least 20 graph for each of the Stocks)

Comment: I see. I'll try to figure out if there is a way to make my answer more generalizable.